# UIManagedDocument and CoreData

Tags: core-data, uimanageddocument

I have watched this years Stanford lectures, and have seen usage of `UIManagedDocument` for interacting with database. It seems very interesting, it seems much easier than usual way.

I would like to use it, but i am unsure how... I know how to open database etc... but what I am more interested is some simple project or tutorial that shows basic proper use of this, you know what goes to app delegate, what should be in seperate class...

Is there something of a kind, because in apress books that deal with iOS they don't mainly do with UIManagedDocument`?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember [this helper class](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html) was recommended in course's forums. It's a good starting point for building a single-threaded Core Data application.